# How to change checkbox's label text in javascript in iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I have checkbox in Script Manager and Update Panel.

Once I click on any row in aspxDevGridView, I would like the checkbox LABEL text to be changed in javascript.

I am calling the javascript from aspxGridViews ClientSide Events.  aspx page is in iframe and I am unable to change the text of checkbox.

```
function OnGridSelect(fldval) {
      document.getElementById("HF_Code").value = fldval[0];
      //I added one label beside checkbox to display the value and it worked
      //but unable to change the text of CB_Asset with innerHTML 
      //Tried clientID as well which does not work.
      document.getElementById('Lbl_Asset').innerHTML = fldval[2] + " Included";
      document.getElementById("CB_Asset").checked = (fldval[1] == "1");
      document.getElementById("RBL_Cost").value = fldval[2];
  }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to get iframe's inner html:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```